# why does my css not work?

Tags: html, css, slim-lang

I'm not able to call the CSS style, I don't know what the reason is, I'm going to do that. The code is shown below

## orders.scss

```
table{
  width:30em;
  table-layout:fixed;
}

td {
    width:100%;
    word-break:keep-all;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

## order.html.slim

```
.row
  .col-md-9
    .box.box-primary
      .box-header.with-border
        h3.box-title 列表
      .box-body.no-padding
        table.table
          tbody
            tr
              th 手机号

              tr
                td = 123456
```

Comment: I don't know what html you are showing; this isn't html.  The tags should have braces, like `<tag>`

Comment: My first guess is because you are not using HTML

Comment: I see you might be using slim:http://slim-lang.com/.  But it compiles to output HTML. You should post that instead.  It is as simple as pressing `ctrl-u` on your browser window.

Comment: Be more specific. What does "I'm not able to call the CSS style, I don't know what the reason is, I'm going to do that." mean?

Comment: 列表 character set is not supported. You can only use ASCII characters.

Comment: @StuiterSlurf Sorry? Why are you saying that?

Comment: Please include the actual HTML and CSS, not any preprocessed stuff, unless your problem is with the preprocessors themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I am a new guy. The reason for the problem is that I didn't properly refer to the `orders.scss` style.

Since the project is using [slim](http://slim-lang.com/).  At the beign of `orders.html.slim`,I need to add the following code:

```
- content_for :preload_stylesheets
  =stylesheet_link_tag   'orders', media: 'all'
```

Then `config/initializes/assets` add the following code :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
...
orders.scss
...
)
```

Finally，it can implement the reference of `orders.scss`